# Mixing integer arithmetic with boolean - Z3 prover

Tags: c++, z3

Before reading this question please consider that it is intended for use with the Z3 solver tool and it's c++ api (everything is redefined so it's not normal c++ syntax)

Can someone explain how do I mix boolean logic with integers (programing wise)?
Example:

```
y =  (x > 10 and x < 100) //y hsould be true or false (boolean)
z =  (y == true and k > 20 and k < 200)
m =  (z or w) //suppose w takes true of false (boolean)
```

I tried with the examples given in the c++ file but I can't figure out how it works when mixing integer arithmetic and boolean.

Comment: Well, take x>10. If x is 3, so the Expression is false. So it's not about arithmetic, really, but they are logic expressions which will be solved by using the right order of precedence for boolean arithmetic.

Comment: What is it you don't understand? The result of `x > 10` is a `bool`.

Comment: In C++ an expression like `z or w` (which is the same as `z || w` for those that wonder) is either `true` or `false`, which corresponds to the integer values `1` and `0`. Considering you use `k` earlier as an integer value (I assume) when getting the result for `z`, are you sure you want to assign the result of `z or w` to `k`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm sorry, I edited it.

Comment: Maybe you'd be better off showing the actual program you've written so far, i.e. the one that uses Z3's API to construct the solver, the terms, etc.

Comment: Just in case the confusion lies with conversions: Z3 will not convert Booleans to integers or vice versa; you have to do that explicitly. Using a similar flavour of syntax to the question: for example, true + false = 1 is an illegal formula, but (if true then 1 else 0) + (if false then 1 else 0) = 1 is fine (and probably what you want?).

Answer (score 0):

Writing answer assuming you a beginner of c++.

May be you are looking for this.

```
bool y,z,m,w;
int x, k; 
y = (x>10 && x<100);  
z = (y == true && k > 20 && k < 200);
m = (z || w);
```

Let see what this line means:
    y = (x>10 && x<100);

here if `x` is greater than 10 `x>10` results `true`. In the same way if `x` is less than 100 `x<100` results `true`. if both of them are `true`, the right side results true, which will be assigned to `y`. 
`||` means or.